# Reactjs & jest -> How to use global varaiables for tests

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

I am trying to set a JS variable set by facebook sdk in my test file

```
beforeall() {  global.FB = true; }
```

I want to change this to false, for one specific test case,Can this be achieved?

I tried setting setting it to false within the test case, and updating the wrapper. but it does not refresh

```
it('test case', () => {
     global.FB = false;
     wrapper.update();
});
```

Comment: are you using enzyme??? Try rendering after you set the global.FB value instead of rendering then setting global value and then updating

Comment: Use window object to set variable globally

Comment: @nikhilmehta I am using enzyme. After setting global i did unmount & mount , it worked after that

Comment: @ArshadHussain thanks